# How to use IntelliJ Liveedit with php include

Tags: php, plugins, intellij-idea, liveedit

I've been working on a webpage and I wanted to break it out into templates that I could pull in. For example the navbar is common to all of the webpages so it gets pulled in like this.

```
<?php include("templates/navigationBar.html"); ?>
```

As soon as I move the code out of the index.php into the templates directory IntelliJ LiveEdit plugin stops updating the main index.php (that's including stuff from the templates directory) when I make changes to one of the templates.

I figure this is because the IntelliJ IDE is "stupid" and will only tell the plugin to refresh the page when it exactly matches the page I'm working on. Is there any way to map those notifications from my templates folder into any php file that might include them?

http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/WI/LiveEdit
http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/?null&pluginId=7007